# RSA Decryption fails second time with OAEP Padding error

Tags: c#, encryption, tcp, stream, cryptography

To exchange AES-Encrypted messages, I encode the IV for each message with RSA and send it to the other client. This succeeds the first time I send a message, but then fails when sending the second message. The client fails decrypting the IV for the message with an OAEP-padding error.

This is my code:

```
writeAes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345"), rmAes.Key, RSAprovider.ToXmlString(false)); // These are just some sample messages
writeAes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("67890"), rmAes.Key, RSAprovider.ToXmlString(false));

public void writeAes(TcpClient client, byte[] writeBuffer, int offset, byte[] AESkey, string RSAXml) //Some of these arguments are optional
{
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.KeySize = 128;
        rijAlg.Key = AESkey;
        rijAlg.GenerateIV();
        // Send IV
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAprovider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096))
        {
            RSAprovider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            RSAprovider.FromXmlString(RSAXml);
            this.write(client, RSAprovider.Encrypt(rijAlg.IV, true));
            logger.Trace("Sent AES IV:\n{0}", BitConverter.ToString(rijAlg.IV).Replace("-", ""));
        }
        // Send Rijndael-encrypted Message
        CryptoStream csEncrypt = null;
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
            csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(client.GetStream(), encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            csEncrypt.Write(writeBuffer, offset, writeBuffer.Length);
            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            encryptor.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            /*if (csEncrypt != null)
                csEncrypt.Dispose();*/
            // TODO: This needs to be disposed somehow but leave the NetworkStream open
        }
    }
}
```

And for receiving:

```
logger.Debug("Got AES-Message:\n" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readAes(connectedClient, new byte[5], 0, aesKey, RSAprovider.ToXmlString(true))));
logger.Debug("Got AES-Message:\n" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readAes(connectedClient, new byte[5], 0, aesKey, RSAprovider.ToXmlString(true))));

public byte[] readAes(TcpClient client, byte[] readBuffer,int offset, byte[] AESkey, string RSAXml) //Some of these arguments are optional
{
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.KeySize = 128;
        rijAlg.Key = AESkey;
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAprovider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096))
        {
            RSAprovider.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            RSAprovider.FromXmlString(RSAXml);
            rijAlg.IV = RSAprovider.Decrypt(this.read(client, new byte[512]), true); //This is where the error occurs on the second message
            logger.Trace("Got AES IV:\n{0}", BitConverter.ToString(rijAlg.IV).Replace("-", ""));
        }
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
            cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(client.GetStream(), decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            int read = 0;
            int error = 0;
            while (read < readBuffer.Length)
            {
                int bytesRead = cryptoStream.Read(readBuffer, read, readBuffer.Length - read);
                read += bytesRead;
                if (bytesRead == 0 && read != error)
                {
                    logger.Debug("Reached end of stream at {0}. Waiting for more data...", read);
                    error = read;
                }
            }
            decryptor.Dispose();
            return readBuffer;
        }
        finally
        {
            /*if (cryptoStream != null)
                cryptoStream.Dispose();*/
            // TODO: This needs to be disposed somehow but leave the NetworkStream open
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that the CryptoStream tries to decrypt more data than is being read, and messes up the IV, but I don't know what I could change to fix this.

Comment: *I encode the IV for each message with RSA* The IV doesn't have to be secret, it just needs to be unique.

Comment: Brilliant, first protect the IV and then forget to protect the ciphertext. Please stick to TLS, don't create your own.

Comment: If the IV doesn't have to be secure, what's the point of it then. It adds randomization, but if an attacker knows how the ciphertext was randomized, then there's no point in it as far as I can tell. Then again, I have never dealt with proper cryptography before. Also, TLS seems to require a certificate authority. My goal is to create a flexible and (almost) serverless p2p network, and TLS wouldn't quite make sense for that.

Comment: You may want to study cryptography before implementing a transport protocol, which is one of the hardest things you can do using common cryptographic primitives. The IV is used to make the ciphertext indistinguishable from random even if the same key is used. TLS doesn't require a certificate authority, alhough most implementations do rely on PKI. Your current scheme does not provide confidentiality, integrity or authentication.

Comment: Havin now read up on TLS, I see why everyone is shouting at me. I would have never thought of some attacks. However, I would still like an answer If someone know what exactly is going on here. I will use TLS for the actual software though.